# I want to create an error register for my PHP program using a bit register

Tags: php, bit, register-allocation

Has anyone tried doing this? It is quite common in my work with PLCs but I have yet to use it in php.

The idea is to use a binary number as a register for various errors so that they are collected easily. The idea would be something like

```
<?php 
if(isset($errorcode)){
if(getrightmostbit($errorcode) = 1){
echo "error 1";
}
$errocode << 1;
if(getrightmostbit($errorcode) = 1){
echo "error 2";
}
$errocode << 1;
if(getrightmostbit($errorcode) = 1){

echo "error 3";
}
```

Any thoughts?

I would ideally then like to use this register as a condition.

Comment: Why would you do this in PHP? Just use an array of all the error messages.

Comment: This is the kind of hack you do on PLCs because they have very lmited memory, so you have to pack lots of information in a small space. PHP is used on servers with plenty of memory, and we go for clarity rather than squeezing data together.